# Washed out colors on a Macbook Pro; the usual answer doesn't work

Tags: display, macbook, xrandr, colors

Xubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook Pro 2012 version.

```
r@r-MacBookPro:~$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
   1280x800       60.2*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
r@r-MacBookPro:~$ xrandr --output LVDS1   --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  47
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `xrandr --verbose` & `xrandr --prop`